# Interquartile range in a symmetric distribution

Tags: statistics

My text book says:

"If a distribution is symmetric, the median plus or minus the semi-interquartile range contains half the scores in the distribution."

I have a simple example set: {1,4,8,12,15}

It is symmetric:

1 _ _ 4 _ _ _ 8 _ _ _ 12 _ _ 15

Median M = Mean = (1 + 4 + 8 + 12 + 15)/5 = 40/5 = 8

Percentile ranks:
p = (r-1)/(n-1), where r for rank, n for size of set

r (25%) = 1 + .25(n-1) = 2
r (50%) = 1 + .5(n-1)  = 3
r (75%) = 1 + .75(n-1) = 4

Percentile values:
v (25%) => 4
v (50%) => 8
v (75%) => 12

Semi-interquartile range:
R/2 = 0.5(v (75%) - v (25%)) = 0.5(12 - 4) = 4

Following the text book, then
M + R/2 = 8 + 4 = 12
M - R/2 = 8 - 4 = 4

Half the values would mean to me:
(M + R/2) - (M - R/2) = 12 - 4 = 8

Total range:
TR = 15 - 1 = 14
then,
1/2TR = 7 which is not equal to 8

I believe I do not understand what the text book says.
May I know the mistake in my understanding?
Perhaps an example could help me understand.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Half the scores in the distribution" $\neq$ "half of the interval of real numbers between the minimum and the maximum". For example, in the set {1, 2, 2, 3}, the interval [1.9, 2.1] (for example) contains half the distribution but is only one-tenth the range.

Comment: Several different formulas for quartiles are in use. They are all pretty much the same for large datasets, but can differ markedly for small datasets. In your case with $n=5$ _any_ formula is going to have trouble isolating the 'middle half' of the observations. Which observation are you going to cut in half? Maybe your book should say "...contains _roughly_ half the scores...$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written

$M + R/2 = 8 + 4 = 12$

$M - R/2 = 8 - 4 = 4$

where $M$ is the median and $R$ the semi-interquartile range

Clearly three of the five terms of $\{1,4,8,12,15\}$ are in the interval $[4,12]$

Three is about as close as you can get to half of five when considering integers, and this is what your textbook is saying